# Stencil web components + ionic native health + capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, healthkit, capacitor

I am trying to use the native health kit in a stencil app. But health is always undefined.

I am using capacitor and stenciljs with native web components.

Msg: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAvailable' of undefined

Anyone else had this issue?

```
import { Component, State, h } from "@stencil/core";
import { Health } from "@ionic-native/health/ngx";

@Component({
  tag: "list-stats"
})
export class ListStats {
  private health: Health;

  componentDidLoad() {

    this.health
      .isAvailable()
      .then((available: boolean) => {
        console.log(available);
        this.health
          .requestAuthorization([
            "distance",
            "nutrition", //read and write permissions
            {
              read: ["steps"], //read only permission
              write: ["height", "weight"] //write only permission
            }
          ])
          .then(res => console.log(res))
          .catch(e => console.log(e));
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }



  render() {
    return [
     <ion-label>
      <p>Steps</p>
     </ion-label>
    ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Inject` the Health class since it's a singleton.
Just add a constructor method and Inject the `Health` class like the following.

```
export class ListStats {
constructor(private health: Health) { }
...
}
```

Comment: I'm not using angular, using stencil web components.
I can try this
constructor() {
this.health = new Health();
 }

Comment: @MichaelBell yes, that should work as well, since your error is that the instace of the class `Health` was never instantiated. let me know if it worked.

Comment: hmm looks like there are some angular/core dependancies required :(

2019-10-26 15:36:56.661 14384-14384/in.clubtiger E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/build/core-207a0272.js - Line 65 - Msg: TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@angular/core". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
2019-10-26 15:36:56.662 14384-14384/in.clubtiger E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/build/core-207a0272.js - Line 1775 - Msg: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Constructor for "list-stats#" was not found